# Using complex variables to find sums of Fourier series

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

Use complex variables to find the sum of the Fourier Series:

$$\sin(\theta) + \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{2^{2}} + \frac{\sin(3\theta)}{2^{3}}+\cdots$$

where $\theta$ is a real variable.

Comment: Why is the first term $\sin(\theta)$ while the other ones are of the form $\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{2^n}$?

Comment: I thought the same thing, but it is written correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{2^n}=\text{Im}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}}{2}\right)^n =\text{Im}\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}}{2-e^{i\theta}}\right)=\text{Im}\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}(2-e^{-i\theta})}{5-4\cos\theta}\right)$$
hence:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{2^n}=\frac{2\sin\theta}{5-4\cos\theta}.$$

Comment: Almost ... The first term in the post was $\sin \theta$, not $\frac12 \sin \theta$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: but the other terms are $\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{2^n}$, so I bet there is a typo in the question. Anyway, what I wrote is correct.

Comment: Yes it is ... I took the liberty of writing a solution with the OP's series as written ... oh, well ...

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\begin{align}
f(\theta)&=\sin\theta + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sin k\theta}{2^k} \tag 1\\\\
&=\sin\theta+\text{Im}\left( \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}}{2}\right)^k\right) \tag 2\\\\
&=\sin\theta+\text{Im}\left(\frac{e^{i2\theta}}{2-e^{i\theta}}\right) \tag 3\\\\
&=\sin\theta+\frac12 \frac{2\sin 2 \theta-\sin \theta}{5-4\cos \theta} \tag 4\\\\
&=\frac12 \frac{9 \sin \theta-2\sin 2\theta}{5-4\cos \theta}\tag 5
\end{align}$$

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we note that the imaginary part of $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta$ is $\sin \theta$ and thus write $\sin \theta=\text{Im}(e^{ \theta})$.  We also make use of the fact that $e^{ik\theta}=\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^k$.

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we made use of the sum for a geometric series $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}r^k=\frac{r^m}{1-r}$ with $r=\frac{e^{i\theta}}{2}$.

In going from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we multiplied both numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator, thereby rendering the denominator real and equal to the square of the magnitude of $2-e^{i\theta}$.

---

**NOTE:**

We remark that if the first term of the series were $\frac{\sin \theta}{2}$ rather than $\sin \theta$, then $(5)$ would be

$$\begin{align}
\frac12 \frac{9 \sin \theta-2\sin 2\theta}{5-4\cos \theta}-\frac 12 \sin \theta &=\frac12 \frac{9\sin \theta-2\sin 2 \theta-(5\sin \theta -2 \sin 2\theta)}{5-4\cos \theta}\\\\
&=\frac{2\sin \theta}{5-4\cos \theta}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Do you know where I can read about making the conversions in your 1st 3 steps (lines 2,3 and 4)? I know Euler's equation, the exponential representation of sin and cos, and some of the double angle identities, but I'm just not following your steps. I want to understand how to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tom Sure.  I'll edit and embed the explanations.

Comment: @Tom You're welcome.  My pleasure!  I just wanted to give you the best answer I could.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the observation that $$\sin(n\theta)=\Im(e^{in\theta})$$
And that the imaginary part is a linear operator.